# Send signals to a debugged nodejs application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a simple nodejs application like

```
...
function checkTermination () {
  console.log('start closing ...');
  ...
}
process.on('SIGTERM', checkTermination);
process.on('SIGINT', checkTermination);
```

I'm debugging it with Visual Studio Code.

Is there an opportunity to send some signals like `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` to the application with "Visual Studio Code" ? How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the process ID
2. Send the Signal

I have a program named test.js, attached to VS code.

```
ps aux | grep node | grep test
//Result
user1           3580   0.0  0.2  3115916  35648   ??  S     3:29PM   0:00.29 /usr/local/bin/node --inspect-brk=48750 test.js
// Send the signal
kill -TERM 3580 // 3580 is the PID
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When launched:

- Pressing **Stop** button in **Debug toolbar** once (Run > Stop Debugging, or Shift + F5), sends `'SIGINT'` signal to your process

  - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug/blob/89cc7d241064f3be21aaeaf3279f4181f61f6ae4/src/node/nodeDebug.ts#L1602-L1610
- Pressing it for a second time, it sends `'SIGKILL'`

  - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug/blob/89cc7d241064f3be21aaeaf3279f4181f61f6ae4/src/node/nodeDebug.ts#L1612-L1618

When attached to:

- Pressing **Stop**, immediately disconnects

  - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug/blob/89cc7d241064f3be21aaeaf3279f4181f61f6ae4/src/node/nodeDebug.ts#L1630-L1638

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug/issues/1#issuecomment-405123769